# Change Dropzone url dynamically

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm trying to change the URL in dropzone, and info I've found hasn't seemed to work for me. I have a form that I'm putting a dropzone in using JS. I'd like to change the dropzone URL depending on what option is selected in a dropdown. Here's the code I'm working with:

**Dropzone**

```
<select id="bioImages" name="bioImages" style="width: 300px;" onchange="urlSetter();">
        <option value="countryFlag">Country Flag</option>
        <option value="locationImg">Location Image</option>
        <option value="nationalAnthemaud">National Anthem</option>
        <option value="countryNameaud">Country Name</option>
</select>
<form id="dropzoneUpload" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="half clearfix">
        <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone" name="fileUpload">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            Drop image/audio here or click to upload (system supports 1 file per category).
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Add Dropzone**

```
function addDropzone() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
            url: "url.com",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response);
             }
        });
    });
}
```

**Change URL**

```
function urlSetter() {
    var drop = document.getElementById('dropzoneUpload');
    if(type.includes('aud')) {
        drop.options.url = 'url.com';
    } else {
        drop.options.url = 'url2.org';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change dropzone url using this way. so to do this first create a global variable and on drop down change event(urlSetter) set the value of that variable like below:

```
var dropzonePostUrl='url.com';
function urlSetter() {
    var drop = document.getElementById('dropzoneUpload');
    if(type.includes('aud')) {
        dropzonePostUrl = 'url.com';
    } else {
        dropzonePostUrl = 'url2.org';
    }
}
```

you also need to change your dropzone initialization code as below:

```
function addDropzone() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
            url: "url.com",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response);
             },
            init: function () {
               var _this=this;
                this.on("processing", function (file) {
                    _this.options.url = dropzonePostUrl;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

you can change url in processing event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addDropzone() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
      url: "url.com",
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      success: function (file, response) {
       console.log(response);
      },
      init: function () {
       this.on("processing", function (file) {
         this.options.url = dropzonePostUrl;
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
var dropzonePostUrl='url.com';
function urlSetter() {
  var drop = document.getElementById('dropzoneUpload');
  if(type.includes('aud')) {
  dropzonePostUrl = 'url.com';
  } else {
  dropzonePostUrl = 'url2.org';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="bioImages" name="bioImages" style="width: 300px;" onchange="urlSetter();">
  <option value="countryFlag">Country Flag</option>
  <option value="locationImg">Location Image</option>
  <option value="nationalAnthemaud">National Anthem</option>
  <option value="countryNameaud">Country Name</option>
</select>
<form id="dropzoneUpload" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <div class="clearfix">
   <br><br>
 </div>
 <div class="half clearfix">
   <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone" name="fileUpload">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message">
     Drop image/audio here or click to upload (system supports 1 file per category).
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```