# How to update Dropzone URL Dynamically

Tags: jquery, dropzone

I've tried a few different ways but I cant get this to work.

I'm trying to follow this answer here [Change Dropzone url dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063626/change-dropzone-url-dynamically)

I have a for with various fields and two instances of dropzone. One works fine however, this one need to upload files to dropbox based on dynamically generated links for each file.

I'm trying to update the dropzone url parameter for each file that is processed based on an ajax response from the server.

I know the ajax works and fetches the URL that I need.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
    jQuery("#files-uploader").dropzone({        
        url: 'url.com',
        init: function(){   

            var dropzoneobject=this;
            this.on("processing", function (file) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:vendor_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    type:'POST',
                    data:'action=knpGetUploadLink&filename='+file['name'],                  
                    success: function(data){
                        //data = a URL returned from the server
                        dropzoneobject.options.url = data;
                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }
                });            
            });

        },
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
        },
        success: function (file, response) {
            console.log(response);
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        },
        error: function (file, response) {
            console.log(response);
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        },
        // update the following section is for removing image from library
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function(file) {}

    });

});
```

Logging the data variable to the console says the correct URL has been returned from the server. 
Logging the dropzoneobject.options.url inside the ajax success parameter shows the correct URL being set. 
Dropzone says it has successfully uploaded but, the network tab in dev tools says the URL posted to was url.com.

I think my timing is messed up somewhere.

Any advice would be great.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was all to do with timing.

Swapped out the processing event and set autoProcessQueue to false.

Then fired processQueue when the ajax call had finished.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
jQuery("#files-uploader").dropzone({        
    url: 'url.com',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function(){   

        var dropzoneobject=this;
        console.log(dropzoneobject);
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        jQuery.ajax({
                url:vendor_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                type:'POST',
                data:'action=knpGetUploadLink&filename='+file['name'],                  
                success: function(data){
                    dropzoneobject.options.url = data;
                    dropzoneobject.processQueue();
                },
                error: function(){

                }
            });

        });
    },
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    success: function (file, response) {
        //console.log(response);
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        //console.log(response);
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
    },
    // update the following section is for removing image from library
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function(file) {}

});

})
```